# Inheriting functions for template classes with multiple template parameters and partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-specialization

Consider the following problem: Given a class `ABase`, that depends on two template parameters `a, b`, there is a function `fcn_base()`, that is independent of both, and a function `fcn()` that depends purely on `a`. I figured, the best technique to write a proper implementation is the following:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int a, int b> 
class ABase {
public: 
    ABase() = default; 
    virtual void fcn() = 0; 
    void fcn_base();
};

template<int a, int b>
class A : public ABase<a, b> {
public: 
    A() = default; 
    void fcn() override;
};

// Specialization for a = 0
template<int b>
class A<0, b> {
public: 
    A() = default;
    void fcn();
};

// Specialization for a = 1
template<int b>
class A<1, b> {
public: 
    A() = default;
    void fcn();
};

template class ABase<0, 1>;
template class ABase<1, 1>;
template class ABase<2, 1>;

template class A<0, 1>; 
template class A<1, 1>; 
template class A<2, 1>; 

template<int a, int b>
void ABase<a, b>::fcn_base(){
    std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl; 
}


template<int a, int b>
void A<a, b>::fcn(){
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
}

template<int b> 
void A<0, b>::fcn(){
    std::cout << "a = 0" << std::endl;
}

template<int b>
void A<1, b>::fcn(){
    std::cout << "a = 1" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    A<0, 1> a0;
    A<1, 1> a1; 
    A<2, 1> a2; 
    
    a0.fcn();
    a1.fcn();
    a2.fcn();
    

    a1.fcn_base(); // Error: has no member fcn_base(). Why?
    a2.fcn_base(); // fine
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile this piece of code results in an error of the type 'has no member'.

I suppose the reason here is simply, that the partial specialization [at compile-time?] declares a new class entirely that is in fact not inheriting from ABase.

However, even after changing that, i.e. typing `class A<1, b> : public ABase<1, b>`, results in an error of the type 'inaccesible within this context'. This could not be resolved with the call `a1.ABase<1, 1>::fcn_base()`.

Do you happen to have any insights on what happens here in this scenario and how to correctly do this?

Edit: I forgot to add the public keyword in my editior, hence the compiler error.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, I tried that [pbviously...], and it still didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering on why it didn't work in my editor. Just forgot to type in the `public' keyword in the inheritance.

Comment: Yeah, that's clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

When you specialize a class, you create a completely new type. As a consequence, if the unspecialized template has `ABase` as a base class, it doesn't mean that the specialized class automatically has this base class as well. So you need to specify the base class in the specializations again:

```cpp
// Specialization for a = 0
template<int b>
class A<0, b> : public ABase<0, b> {
public: 
    A() = default;
    void fcn();
};

// Specialization for a = 1
template<int b>
class A<1, b> : public ABase<1, b> {
public: 
    A() = default;
    void fcn();
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/saWc51EWa